Sequence of tasks in Multithreading
I am new to threads and multithreading.(Win socket API)
I am trying to achieve the sequence of tasks in 2 threads with proper synchronization.
no. of threads 2 :  Thread_A and Thread_B
Thread_A{
    
    print task_A
    
    print task_D
}

Thread_B{
    
    print task_B
    
    print task_C
}

The expected output should be print task_A , print task_B,  print task_C, print task_D.
do i need to use 2 semaphores or 1 can be use ??
Thread_A{

while(1){

    wait semaphore

           print task_A

    release semaphore
        
    wait semaphore

           print task_D

    release semaphore
}

}

Thread_B{

while(1){

       wait semaphore

           print task_B
    
           print task_C

      release semaphore

}

}

for once it goes A,B,C,D but second time B,C, A,B

Welcome new user!  You'd probably just use 1x semaphore to wait on ThreadB, after you print A.  Please tap "edit" and fix your code formatting. To format code, highlight the entire code block and tap the "code" {} icon.

ok, on second Iteration, the print A get executed out of sequence.

I have tried with condition variables to ensure that task 1 is performed before task 2 and also for task 3 and 4.
ref : Windows control variable Inital value of done and flag is 0
Thread 1

  while(1){
    
            EnterCriticalSection (&Tx_data);
            while (done == 1 )
            {
                SleepConditionVariableCS (&Status, &Tx_data, INFINITE);
            }
                printf("\n  1  "); // task A

                done =1;
                flag =0;
            LeaveCriticalSection (&Tx_data);
            WakeConditionVariable (&Status);


            EnterCriticalSection (&Tx_data);
            while (flag == 0 )
            {
                SleepConditionVariableCS (&flags, &Tx_data, INFINITE);
            }
                printf(" 4  "); // task D

            LeaveCriticalSection (&Tx_data);
            WakeConditionVariable (&Status);
}

Thread 2

     while(1){
    
            EnterCriticalSection (&Tx_data);
            while (done == 0 )
            {
                SleepConditionVariableCS (&Status, &Tx_data, INFINITE);
            }
                printf("  2  ");// task B
                printf("  3  ");// task C
                done =0;
                flag =1;
                
             LeaveCriticalSection (&Tx_data);
             WakeConditionVariable (&flags);
             WakeConditionVariable (&Status);
    }

The result ok and look like
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
is this approach with the use of condition variable to sequentially operate 1 2 3 4 tasks correct ?. It works for few tests, but is it reliable and fail proof ?

Don't add more question as an answer, this will be deleted by the mods.  Simply edit your question and add as much as you like

When your program starts those two tasks, what guarantees that Thread_A will acquire the semaphore before Thread_B acquires it? Certainly, there's nothing in your program (at least, nothing in the part of your program that you've showed) that guarantees it.
And, when Thread_A releases the semaphore and then immediately tries to acquire it again, what guarantees that Thread_B will get it first? Again, there's nothing in your program that guarantees it.
Your example uses the semaphore like a mutex, and you can't achieve that kind of sequencing with a mutex.

do i need to use 2 semaphores...?

That's what I would do. I'd have, for example, task_A release task_B's semaphore to signal that it's task_B's turn to run, and then task_A would acquire its own semaphore to wait for its own turn again.

But NOTE!
When you use two or more threads in this way, where each thread waits its turn, and no two threads are ever doing any interesting things at the same time, then that defeats the entire purpose of multi-threading. The only reason to ever create a thread is so that it can do something* at the same time as other threads in the program are doing their things.
*Even if it's only just waiting for input from the user or waiting for a message from a remote network host, that's still a "thing" that the thread can be doing at the same time as other threads doing their things.

You have exactly pointed out the questions I had in my mind. How to ensure that Thread_A will acquire the semaphore before Thread_B or task A is executed before task C. I will try to utilize the idea of 2 semaphores.

The hint about the purpose of multi-threading : I would like to utilize the concept of thread to separate the communication between 2 networks. The goal is to transfer the data between the 2 sperate networks. *Step 1. Collect data from network A, modify the data. *Step 2. Send the modified data to the network B. *Step 3 Receive the data from network B. *Step 4 Send the data received from the network B to the network A.  All the steps must be done in sequence. I am not sure, whether using Multi-threading is best way to achieve the goal.

@YashwantRao regarding your comment just there.  It's difficult to know what you are doing, but, that sounds like it has nothing at all to do with multitasking - heh!  Whenever you are receiving data, in almost all cases, you wait until you have received it all.  (The rare exceptions, irrelevant here, are things like video streaming.) All you are saying is that in step 3, you must (of course, obviously, as normal) wait for all data before proceeding.  Does that help?

@YashwantRao i suggest you tick this answer (which literally answereed the question you asked) and ask a completely new question about what you are doing including some code samples.  Note - you should defiiutely vote up (as well as ultimately tick) answers such as this, so that, as a new user you yourself garner ponts, so that you can ask more questions etc

@YashwantRao, Re, "I would like to...separate the communication between 2 networks." Separating the source code and separating the actions are two different ideas. Use threads when you want different actions to happen independently of each other. But in this case, you want the actions to happen in strict sequence. You can't separate them. There are other ways to separate the source code objects/functions/modules that talk to the two different networks if that's what you want, but don't use threads. Using two threads only obscures the fact that the sequence of actions is important.

@SolomonSlow I understood, its better to do with function calls and avoid use of threads here.

@SolomonSlow   I am curious to understand better. The producer/consumer problem and Rendezvous problem, both solutions are designed with multi-threading. However, both doesn't truly utilize the benefit of threading concept, instead they are some how sequential in nature ?
